# how does spring-boot get the params from url that use ? to connect params

Tags: java, html, spring, web, url

for example

@RequestMapping("/category")

```
@DeleteMapping
public R<String> delete(Long id) {
    System.out.println(id);},
```

the target urls is " http://localhost:8080/category?id=1519009702132219905".
and my question is how does spring-boot get the "id", how does it know Long id = 1519009702132219905.just for the same name?
I want to know the principle in this.

pls help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RequestParam annotation

```
@DeleteMapping
public R<String> delete(@RequestParam Long id) {
    System.out.println(id);},
```

Comment: of course i know it can work in this way.But i want to know the principle of my way.My way work correctly too